# count images in local folder WinRT

Tags: winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I am new in WinRT , 
Is it possible to count number of images in Assest Folder . So that we can do few operation over it .
Presently i am making a small app.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
var folder = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var files = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

and get the files count as

```
var filesCount = files.Count;
```

and you can get the files count of specific extension as

```
var pngFileCount = files.Where(file => file.FileType == ".png").Select(f => f).ToList().Count;
```

Hope this will helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
var folder = await Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets");
var options = new QueryOptions { FileTypeFilter = { ".png", ".jpg" } };
var query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(options);
var files = await query.GetFilesAsync();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    // TODO
}
```

I want to point out that this works in Windows but not Windows Phone. Not yet.

Best is luck.